# Executing calculations in linked spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a fairly complex VBA userform in an Excel spreadsheet file (let's call it S1).  One of the outputs of this userform is a string of data that drops into a tab.

This string of data is linked in to another spreadsheet (S2).  This is done by simply linking cells from S2 to S1, e.g. =S1,tab!A2.

Calculations are then undertaken in S2, and a string of outputs are created in S2.  These outputs in S2 are linked back to cells in S1 (same basic method).

I want this whole process to run automatically whilst I am executing the userform in S1, i.e. while the form is still up, I want the links to be refreshed, calculations to be made, and then bring that new information into the Userform.

This works OK if both spreadsheets are open at the same time, but that's not practical.  Also, there will ultimately be several other downstream linked spreadsheets.

Right now, however, whilst I can drop the string of data into S1, and pick up the new data from S1 - the calculation using that data is not being refreshed in S2.

I have added a script to a macro that is called in the userform to drop data into S1 and pick up the calculated data in S1.

Doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:= _
    "T:\_x\x\xx\S2.xlsx" _
    , Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Hoping there is a way to get these links / calculations refreshed mid stream.

Comment: There are 2 ways. `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Calculate` the first one will refresh everything on your workbook, the  second will recalculate anything on that sheet.

Comment: Thanks Damian - but doesn't seem to work.  It refreshes the current workbook, but I need it also to refresh the calculation in other linked workbooks, i.e. S1 is refreshing, but still pulling old info from S2 because S2 is not refreshed.

Comment: Ah! That's different, are your workbooks open? If so, make a loop through all the workbooks using the `Workbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: Ideally, the downstream workbooks will all be closed.  Can I push a loop through them without opening them, and if so, how?

Comment: Open-Refresh-Refresh your workbook-Close and repeat. Or open them all, refresh them all and then refresh yours to finally close them. You need to open them, Though you can do that disabling screen updating so the user won't notice "much" or making the application invisible.

Comment: Thanks... is there a way I can import the code / calculations into the main sheet without physically moving all the tabs across?

Comment: Thanks - a little clunky but seems to work OK.  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't what do you want to import? Data to the sheet?

Comment: Yes, no worries - I've managed to get your solution working... seems to be good!